# How can i sort the matplotlib graph in ascending or descending order?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSYsL.png)
The result is just random graph without any order. Any help is appreciated

```
importances = selector_clf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in 
selector_clf.estimators_],
         axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [14,15]
plt.barh(range(len(predictors_tree)),std, color='lightgreen')
plt.ylabel("Predictors")
plt.xlabel("Importance")
plt.title("Importance Score")
plt.yticks(range(len(predictors_tree)), predictors_tree)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does the data look like? What does the graph look like? Please create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just uploaded a link to the image. Please see the link with the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different feature importances are not sorted out directly; you have to sort them manually. This can be done with `np.sort` (and `np.argsort` in order to sort the predictor trees based on feature importance standard deviations). The code below should do the trick.

```py
importances = selector_clf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in 
selector_clf.estimators_],
         axis=0)

# Get sorted std and sorting index, and sort predictor tree
std_sorded = np.sort(std)
sorting_index = np.argsort(std)
predictor_tree = [predictor_tree[s] for s in sorting_index]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [14,15]
plt.barh(range(len(predictors_tree)), std_sorded, color='lightgreen')
plt.ylabel("Predictors")
plt.xlabel("Importance")
plt.title("Importance Score")
plt.yticks(range(len(predictors_tree)), predictors_tree)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Leonard! It seems like the function worked but its not sorting it out from highest to lowest STDDEV. Please see the image I have attached with the post. There is a link . Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this was my guess indeed. The code I provided you with will actually do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your axes are dependent upon each other so I would sort your std array before plt.barh

The docs give [these examples](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
a = np.array([[1,4],[3,1]])
np.sort(a)                # sort along the last axis

#array([[1, 4],
#       [1, 3]])

np.sort(a, axis=None)     # sort the flattened array

#array([1, 1, 3, 4])

np.sort(a, axis=0)        # sort along the first axis

#array([[1, 1],
#       [3, 4]])
```

One of those should work for ascending then you can use [np.flip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) for descending.